# Getting Exceptions org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody and javax/mail/internet/AddressException

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-mail

I am getting above two exceptions one by one.
1.  javax/mail/internet/AddressException 
2.  org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody

I have added both dependencies in my Pom.XML 
if i replace dependency of javax.mail then it goes and org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody exception comes  and after changing version of httpmime javax.mail exceptions thrown.

My Pom.XML

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>DishTv</groupId>
  <artifactId>AutoPull</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>AutoPull</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-win -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
          <artifactId>httpclient-win</artifactId>
          <version>4.5.1</version>
      </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-cache -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
          <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.6</version>
      </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>DishTv.App</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

      </plugins>
    </plugin Management>
  </build>
</project>
```

Please help.

Comment: When did you get these exceptions? Post the full statcktrace please.

Comment: when i am trying to run JAR file which is generated after maven command clean install -U.

D:\CT\AutoPull\target>java -jar AutoPull-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: You've got three different JavaMail dependencies, with different versions.  That's not going to work.  You only need one JavaMail dependency - com.sun.mail:javax.mail.  Ideally you would use the latest version - 1.6.2.  If making those changes still doesn't work, post more details about the exceptions you're getting.

Comment: Now i am only using <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>

But i am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody